Ubuntu Studio 23.10, no sound on 10 year old PCs. The system said: "IO error"
I have installed Ubuntu Studio 23.10 on my 10 year old Dell Precision M4700 and a Surface Pro 4, both with the same problem.
After booting, I go to Audio - System Settings and try to test sound through the PC Speakers. The GUI then hangs for a couple of minutes, before displaying an IO error.
Is trying to get this to work on such old PC a futile endeavor or does someone have some help to offer?
The hang situation happens on both PulseWire (bumped up to v1) and re-configuring (using switch configuration) to Jack. In Jack config without starting Jack, it works OK.
IO error:

qpwgraph:


For the Surface Pro 4, use the linux-surface repository https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup. After successfully setting it up sound should work. The feature matrix says sound is supported https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Supported-Devices-and-Features#feature-matrix

Thanks for pointing out the Surface repository.
I just used a Live USB boot for testing the Surface, as the Dell M4700 is the unit I had set aside for Audio work. Might need to go with a newer PC though. Will test a 5yr old Acer this weekend.

After upgrading to 24.04 LTS internal audio woks just fine on the Dell M4700.
